# Get Picklist Values based on Record Type

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, schema

Am designing a JQuery AutoComplete search box in visualforce page and getting the data source from controller class from two picklist fields(Controlling and dependent). The autocomplete search box works fine but it loads all the values from the picklist fields. I want to load the picklist values based on record type. Here

```
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> contrEntries = ctrlField.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
for (Schema.PicklistEntry ple : contrEntries) {
    String label = ple.getLabel();
    objResults.put(label, new List<String>());
    controllingValues.add(label);
}
```

Can we add the picklist values based on particular record type?.

I found that this can be done using MetaData API, but I don't want to deploy all the MetaData files into our client org.

Can be done using describeLayout?. If yes, please help me to understand.

Answer (score 3):

sorry i tried over same issue but didnt get any solution 
but you can get idea by success comunity by rest call

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gNpLAAU

Comment: Just upvoted the same idea. lol.

Answer (score 1):

This is For those who are looking to get picklist values in LWC you can use **UI-API** adapter "**getPicklistValuesByRecordType()**" to get picklist values specific to the record type. More details at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_picklist_values_record

Comment: OP wants to work in Visualforce, not LWC.