# How check with SOQL if a picklist value is available or not for a specified record type

Tags: soql, picklist, record-type

How check if a picklist value is available or not for a specified record type (
through SOQL)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. We ask that questions show that research has been undertaken before asking. Please read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) then [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/332282/edit) your question to explain what you've tried and where you are facing an issue.

Comment: Of course. I need to understand if it is possible to trace the values ​​of a picklist that are available for a given record type through SOQL. Then via query / API. Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is possible via SOQL. Check the posts- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103837/how-do-i-get-the-intersection-of-recordtype-and-picklist-values-inside-apex and https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/201871/get-picklist-values-based-on-record-type

Answer (score 1):

As per now, it is not possible to do it via SOQL neither Apex. You can upvote that idea [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gNpLAAU).

As an alternative, you can take a look at [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103837/how-do-i-get-the-intersection-of-recordtype-and-picklist-values-inside-apex/202519#202519) post (using UI API) or [this one](https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/retrieve-picklist-value-of-a-record-type-using-metadata-service-in-salesforce/) (using Metadata API).

Best regards!